# Why is a SecretKeySpec needed when deriving a key from a password in Java?

Tags: java, cryptography, jce, secret-key

What is difference between `SecretKey` vs `SecretKeySpec` classes in Java?

The documentation of `SecretKeySpec` says:

> it can be used to construct a SecretKey from a byte array

In this code, if I print `secretKey.getEncoded()` or `secret.getEncoded()`, in hex then both give the same output. So why do we need the `SecretKeySpec`?

```
final String password = "test";
int pswdIterations = 65536  ;
int keySize = 256;
byte[] ivBytes;
byte[] saltBytes = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};

SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");

PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(
                    password.toCharArray(), 
                    saltBytes, 
                    pswdIterations, 
                    keySize
                    );

SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);

SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(),"AES");
```

Here is the output of both calls to `getEncoded()`:

`00367171843C185C043DDFB90AA97677F11D02B629DEAFC04F935419D832E697`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Every `SecretKey` has an associated algorithm name. You cannot use a `SecretKey` with algorithm `"DES"` in a context where an AES key is needed, for example.

In your code, the following line produces a `SecretKey`:

```
SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
```

However, at this point the key is *not* an AES key. If you were to call `secretKey.getAlgorithm()`, the result is `"PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1"`. You need some way of telling Java that this is actually an AES key.

The easiest way to do this is to construct a new `SecretKeySpec` object, using the original key data and explicitly specifying the algorithm name:

```
SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(),"AES");
```

Note: I would personally declare `secret` as a `SecretKey`, since I don't think you'll need to care about the concrete implementation after this.

Comment: "Every SecretKey has an associated algorithm name." , wouldn't that make the encryption less secure ? shouldn't key should be independent of the algorithm ? , for instance, If someone got the key, wouldn't they be able to identify the algorithm used for encryption ?

Comment: Strong cryptography works on the basis that everyone knows everything, *except* the value of your key. Once someone has your key, figuring out how you encrypted data is a trivial task. So no, your algorithm need not be secret.

Answer (score 11):

SecretKey is just an interface that requires provider-specific implementation. SecretKeySpec is a concrete class that allows for easy construction of SecretKey from existing key material. So, in order to get SecretKey, you need to use either appropriate factory class or SecretKeySpec, as a shortcut.

Answer (score 6):

`SecretKey` is an interface and `SecretKeySpec` is an implementation of `SecretKey`